# An error occurred while requesting the visualisation's config resource

Tags: looker-studio

I got an error "An error occurred while requesting the visualisation's config resource" while trying to request my custom visualisation. All files have been made public.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Custom Vis",
    "description": "By Sorrow",
    "devMode": true,
    "components": [{
        "id": "Custom Vis",
        "name": "Custom Vis",
        "iconUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googledatastudio/community-visualizations/master/docs/codelab/img/bar_chart.png",
        "description": "Custom Vis",
        "resource": {
            "js": "custom-vis/final.js",
            "config": "custom-vis/config.json",
            "css": "custom-vis/style.css"
        }
    }]
}
```

config.json

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "concepts",
        "label": "Concepts",
        "elements": [
          {
            "id": "barDimension",
            "label": "Dimension",
            "type": "DIMENSION",
            "options": {
              "min": 1,
              "max": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "barMetric",
            "label": "Metric",
            "type": "METRIC",
            "options": {
              "min": 1,
              "max": 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "style": [
      {
        "id": "color",
        "label": "Colors",
        "elements": [
          {
            "type": "FONT_COLOR",
            "id": "barColor",
            "label": "Bar Color",
            "defaultValue": "black"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a folder on the Google Cloud where your files will go:

Then add it like here:

```
"resource": {
        "js": "gs://yourname/index.js",
        "config": "gs://yourname/index.json",
        "css": "gs://yourname/index.css"
}
```

PS: watch a video here https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/local-dev

That will save you a lot of time on development.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same issue.
Resources were provided in the default tutorial in a form of

```
"resource": {
      "js": "MY_GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET/myViz.js",
      "config": "MY_GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET/myViz.json",
      "css": "MY_GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET/myViz.css"
    }
```

What was not clear is that they actually need to include **gs://** in the path. Would be clearer if they explicitly mentioned it like so:

```
"resource": {
      "js": "gs://MY_GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET/myViz.js",
      "config": "gs://MY_GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET/myViz.json",
      "css": "gs://MY_GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET/myViz.css"
    }
```

It must work this way.

Comment: this worked for me - didn't need to create a folder in the cloud storage bucket.

Comment: Creating a dedicated folder is optional, it is given in the tutorial, but it's just for keeping things organized.